# how to do model hook of Ember in React?

Tags: reactjs, ember.js

In Ember when you do route transition there is a model hook for you to retrieve data for this route/page. how to achieve this in React?
thanks.

Comment: Your question is bit too broad to answer. If have any code showing what you have tried to far, it make getting an answer far easier.

Answer (score 0):

React doesn't really have a way to manage data. You'll need an external library for this.

One way you could achieve this, is to use redux-bees: https://github.com/cantierecreativo/redux-bees
or orbit.js: https://github.com/exivity/react-orbitjs/

They'll both require that you add a bunch more dependencies.

You'll need react-router for sure: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router
But this doesn't provide the idea of "routes".

I'm currently working on an open source project for work that uses React + Orbit.js : https://github.com/sillsdev/appbuilder-portal/blob/1bfd8500c04f43695ebc746cda787d7d4d2fdf66/source/SIL.AppBuilder.Portal.Frontend/src/ui/routes/users/edit/index.tsx

Though, I'm kind of building my own framework here, which I'm personally not a huge fan of. :-\